# Popper, Bootstrap 4 and ES2015: Popper not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, popper.js

I am pretty confused on how to make the Javascript utilities in Bootstrap 4 work.

I am using ES2015 style requires. I've installed jQuery, the latest beta of Bootstrap 4 (beta 2) and Popper.js using node modules. Here's how I am loading my JS:

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

$(function() {

  require('popper');
  require('./vendor/bootstrap/index');

});
```

Popper's docs state that you need code like this to instantiate Popper:

```
  var reference = document.querySelector('#dropdownLanguageButton');
  var popper = document.querySelector('div[aria-labelledby="dropdownLanguageButton"]');
  var anotherPopper = new Popper(
      reference,
      popper,
      {
          // popper options here
      }
  );
```

However, it is not clear if you need to instantiate for something as simple as a Bootstrap dropdown.

There is no clear example in the Bootstrap 4 docs.

The error I am getting is `index.js:10 Uncaught ReferenceError: Popper is not defined`.

Help appreciated!

Comment: That doesn't look like ES2015 imports thought, that looks like Commonjs.

Comment: Are you bundling your scripts with webpack?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe problem in path to popper.js. Popper's required file located in 'node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js'